Initial bundle size of Expo Metro Bundles for react native web is coming out to be too large
We are using react native for web application to keep the codebase and maintenance common between web and mobile app. It is built over expo which is using metro bundler by default.
For some reason, the initial bundle size is coming out to be over 6MBs which is increasing the initial load time of the application. There being limited knowledge base about react native for web, I am unable to find a direction which can fix the problem.
